# Is it possible to characterize artinian modules by their support?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Rings are commutative Noetherian (and local if needed). modules are not necessarily finitely generated

---

There are several characterization for a modules to be artinian.
but I want to know whether there is a characterization for artinian modules $M$ based on $\operatorname{Supp}M$?

I can prove that if $M$ is artinian, then all elements of $\operatorname{Supp} M$ are maximal (and $|\operatorname{Supp} M|< \infty$). Is the converse true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $k$ be any field, and let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional $k$-vector space. Then $V$ is neither Artinian nor Noetherian, but $\operatorname{Supp}(V) = \{0\}$ is a finite set of maximal ideals of $k$.

Comment: thank you.  do u know any characterization?

Comment: Not purely in terms of the support, for exactly this reason! Every nontrivial vector space over a field has the same support.

Comment: how about  in terms of the support and something else? :)

Comment: do u know a ref. on characterizations of these modules?--- i only know one characterization with copies of E(R/m)

Comment: I don't know this characterization – what is $E(R/m)$?